How to access whatsapp status file directory in Android 11 and above
I want to make an app which will save the status of whatsaap. How I can access to the directory above android 12 an up.
Access to android direcotry, and files. It showing no files and file count 0 everytime. How to fix this.

Due to security reasons, you can't access that far. Android/data/ is unavailable. It's there, but invisible—hidden.

I want to access to the Android/Media directory

Be ROOT and you will be able to access
